# Zig `Segmentation fault at address`

Tags: zig

Trying to build a Huffman Code using `zig` but getting `Segmentation fault at address 0x7ff700000002`.

I am printing two values:

Expected:

```
tree: huffman.Node{ .freq = 15, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 9, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 0, .value = 328965, .left = huffman.Node{ ... }, .right = huffman.Node{ ... } }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 2977642760, .value = 32759, .left = huffman.Node{ ... }, .right = null } }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 2977642800, .value = 32759, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 3, .value = 197379, .left = null, .right = null }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 2977643128, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ ... }, .right = huffman.Node{ ... } } } }
tree: huffman.Node{ .freq = 9, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 5, .value = 328965, .left = null, .right = null }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 4, .value = 263172, .left = null, .right = null } }
```

But get:

```
tree: huffman.Node{ .freq = 15, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 9, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 0, .value = 328965, .left = huffman.Node{ ... }, .right = huffman.Node{ ... } }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 2977642760, .value = 32759, .left = huffman.Node{ ... }, .right = null } }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 2977642800, .value = 32759, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 3, .value = 197379, .left = null, .right = null }, .right = huffman.Node{ .freq = 2977643128, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ ... }, .right = huffman.Node{ ... } } } }
tree: huffman.Node{ .freq = 9, .value = null, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = 32, .value = 0, .left = huffman.Node{ .freq = Segmentation fault at address 0x7ff700000002
```

(Issue on the second line)

I think it's something on how I am allocating memory, as clearly the `.freq = 32` is totally unexpected and wrong, but tried reading the docs and still can't find why this happens

```
...
    var tree = build_tree(array);
    var code_map = std.HashMap(u32, u32, hash_u32, std.hash_map.default_max_load_percentage).init(gpa);
    // defer code_map.deinit();
    try traverse_tree(1, tree, &code_map); // Code contains an 1 at the start of it
    return code_map;
}

fn traverse_tree(code: u32, tree: Node, map: *std.hash_map.HashMap(u32, u32, hash_u32, std.hash_map.default_max_load_percentage)) !void {
    std.debug.print("tree: {?} \n", .{tree});
    if (tree.value != null) {
        try map.put(tree.value.?, code);
    } else {
        try traverse_tree(code * 2, tree.left.?.*, map);
        try traverse_tree(code * 2 + 1, tree.right.?.*, map);
    }
}

fn build_tree(array: []Node) Node {
    var i: u32 = 1;
    var current: Node = array[0];
    while (i < (array.len - 1)) {
        if (array[i + 1].freq < current.freq) {
            var starting_i = i;
            var ending_i = i;
            while (i < array.len and array[i].freq < current.freq) {
                ending_i += 1;
                i += 1;
            }
            var new_node = build_tree(array[starting_i..ending_i]);
            var tmp = current;
            current = Node{ .freq = tmp.freq + new_node.freq, .value = null, .right = &tmp, .left = &new_node };
        } else {
            var item = array[i];
            var tmp = current;
            current = Node{ .freq = tmp.freq + item.freq, .value = null, .right = &tmp, .left = &item };
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    // Do the last item separatedly. We check if it is smaller to array.len as it might be used in another node before,
    // meaning that i would be grater to array.len
    if (i < array.len) {
        var last = array[array.len - 1];
        var tmp = current;
        current = Node{ .freq = tmp.freq + last.freq, .value = null, .right = &tmp, .left = &last };
    }
    return current;
}
const Node = struct {
    freq: u32,
    value: ?u32,
    left: ?*Node,
    right: ?*Node,
};
```

If I log the `current` variable in the `build_tree` function, the output of it is the expected one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `build_tree` function returns a `Node` with invalid pointers.

For example,

```
var last = array[array.len - 1];
```

What happens here? A `Node` is copied from `array` to the function stack. A pointer to it is only valid until the function exits.

All other instances of taking an address in `build_tree` have the same problem.

You need to correctly take pointers to the existing nodes. And make sure the new nodes are properly allocated and deallocated after use.

The allocation of the new nodes can be done in several ways:

- Using an allocator. But you may need to add a special flag to the `Node` to know which ones to deallocate. Or you can allocate/copy all nodes, so that you can deallocate them en masse later. Or you can use a dedicated allocator just for the new nodes, and deallocate the entire allocator after use.
- If the total number of nodes can be known in advance, you can allocate memory for the new nodes and provide it in the function (basically an array where you'll store the new nodes).